# Не происходит re-render, хотя state в redux изменился

Tags: reactjs, redux, render, state

Не могу понять, почему не происходит ре-рендер тикетов? В дев-тулсе - Redux меняется успешно при кликах по сортировочным табам.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 1):

Вопрос решен. Все дело в мутации данных.

Правильный вариант - использовать Immutable.js либо Immer

"несовсем" правильный - .splice() - для создания нового массива.

[image: "несовсем" правильное решение]